# CSS: How to fix the excess space of symbols like this (when line-height doesn't cut it)

Tags: css

Some special symbols such as ࿊ (`&#4042;`) have a weird spacing, resulting in a styling problem such as this:

https://jsfiddle.net/MirandaN/t9hkv13L/28/

```css
p {
  line-height: 1.4;
}
a::before {
  content: '࿊';
  /* display: inline-block; -- this would remove the background-color without reducing the actual clickable area*/
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: -.1em;            /* to align the symbol vertically with the rest of the line */
  color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  line-height: 0;        /* to make <a> obey <p>'s line-height */
}
```

```html
<body style="font-size: 48px">
  <p>
    Ouch, you mad bro?<br>
    <a href=""></a> Why so damn tall?<br>
    Please get short!
  </p>
</body>
```

The symbol is inserted as a `::before` pseudo-element of `<a>`, originally without a background color. The symbol appeared lower than the rest of its line, so I subtracted its relative top value a little for vertical alignment (after I tried `margin-top` and `padding-top` that didn't fix it).

And its line-height appeared larger than what had been set for `<p>`, so I set this symbol's line-height to 0 (after I tried 1 that didn't fix it). Then I noticed that `<a>`'s clickable area was extending out and into the above line, such that each such portion of the above line could become troublingly clickable. I colored `<a>`'s background to see that its area was really spilling out of its line upward.

I read some suggestion to add `display: inline-block` to such a pseudo-element; in my case, it would remove the element's background color without fixing the excess clickable area.

Can this be solved so that the clickable area of `<a>` with this symbol fits within its line? Or is this extra spacing an inexorable part of the character?

Comment: Has the height being greater than the adjacent line got anything to do with its being a special symbol? If I replace it with a capital X I get a 'too tall' result too.

Comment: The character you inserted simply does not take "full height", it behaves very similar to as if you had just used a lowercase `o` instead. You might need to _specify_ a height, and then tweak the line height, to get close to what you want. Something like this maybe. https://jsfiddle.net/e74d2c9n/

Comment: The difference with normal characters like "X" is that "X" will sit at the vertical middle and equally divide its lineheight between above and below the baseline, whereas ࿊ will for whatever reason sit at the bottom (you can see here that it's already crossing the baseline) such that the rest of its lineheight is all on the upper side, and this can't be fixed with `vertical-align` or `top`.

Answer (score 0):

The height of a glyph is set by the font. Non-Latin glyphs like the one you've chosen may have very different sizes to the usual letter glyphs. In this case, it's exaggerated because you've set `font-size: 1.8em`, which makes the glyph almost twice as tall as the rest of the line!

The best solution to your problem here may be to use an SVG icon (or PNG if you prefer) as the background image, because you can size this precisely using `width` and `height` properties, and the SVG will be the same size as its bounding box, which isn't the case for font glyphs, as you see here.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to set the ackground on your `a` not your before element.

```css
a{
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

As you are having a `position: relative` the line height will be taken on the `a` height, the background will respect now the normal way.

### DEMO

```css
p {
  line-height: 1.4;
  
}
a{
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
a::before {
  content: '࿊';
  /* display: inline-block; -- this would remove the background-color without reducing the actual clickable area*/
  position: relative;
  top: -.1em;            /* to align the symbol vertically with the rest of the line */
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  line-height: 0;        /* to make <a> obey <p>'s line-height */
}
```

```html
<body style="font-size: 48px">
  <p>
    Ouch, you mad bro?<br>
    <a href=""></a> Why so damn tall?<br>
    Please get short!
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: But `a`'s clickable area is still covering the line above (see how the cursor changes when you hover over "Ouch", which is the problem I'm trying to solve). In fact, I don't need to keep the background color; I added it for the purpose of showing how far up the character area of `࿊` extends once I've lifted up from its weird default position at the bottom of the lineheight. I tried to fix this with `vertical-align: text-top`, it didn't work.

Comment: @MirandaN Add this to your `a` as I did: `overflow: hidden;  display: inline-block;  vertical-align:middle;`